# Is it normal that I am able to invoke firebase cloud functions from any kind of frontend app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, express

I am using axios to call the firebase cloud functions I have created with express/firebase. I realized even without using and without importing the firebase and without **initializeApp(firebaseConfig)** in my frontend, I was able to call my cloud functions with the axios with the following way:

```
axios.get('https://us-central1...')
```

How I create cloud functions:

index.js

```
module.exports ={
    ...require('./controllers/foo')
}
```

foo.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: true}));

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Function goes in here
});

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    // Function goes in here
});

app.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    // Function goes in here
});

app.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    // Function goes in here
});

exports.foo = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Is this a normal behavior or is it due to way of working of express (cors as middleware) or axios somehow? Or do I just have to add auth and firestore rules into my database? Whatever the reason is then what is the meaning of the firebaseConfig information that firebase provides for us?

**PS:** Just to play around I have tried to add firestore rules. I have added the following rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Even though in rules playground I was not able to retrieve anything, from my application I still got the query I wanted and I don't know why.

Comment: The security rules for your database have nothing to do with Cloud Functions. They only control access to the database that happens directly from the client.

Comment: If you are calling these functions from an app, its recommended to use callable functions. If you want to implement an authorisation check, you can maybe check out this sample code from firebase: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is absolutely normal. The HTTP Functions are made so you can integrate you Firebase Project with any (absolutely any) other language or platform by using HTTP requests as the `trigger` name shows. As you already do, you can even implement `express` apps behind those requests.

With those you gave full power and `responsebility` what goes trough them and with that comes also the need for you to know who is calling your HTTP requests. if you want to secure them you can use the [link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint) from the comment and check how to make Authorized HTTP Ednpoinds.

If you want to call those just from your App Frontend I would recommend to use [Callable Firebse Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) because those will work only from your app and also provide the data of the user who called them in the `context` of your cloud function triggered.

Comment: I see this is perfect thank you very much. There is only one thing I didnt understand. As far I as I understand we have to manually set the authorization header or the cookie to firebase id token. Where and when should I set this? From the frontend or when user registers / logins?

Comment: You have work on both sides. On the backend you verify the token `const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);` and in the frontent you need to get one after you login like ` firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());`. The github example from the link shows a minimal code you need for it to work.